# Is the HTTPS required between API Gateway and Elastic Beanstalk?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssl, https, aws-api-gateway, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have Elastic Beanstalk (EB) with Elastic Load Balancers (ELB) in public subnet and EC2 instances in private subnet. API Gateway sends requests to ELB via HTTP.

I've set the Client-Side Cert. on EB that only requests from API Gateway are acceptable, so access to my EB is restricted.

Do I need set also typical HTTPS between API Gateway and EB? Or the configuration with HTTP is save enough when access to EB is restricted only to API Gateway?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While HTTPS is not strictly necessary, it is definitely preferred.

There is currently no way to restrict access to your EB such that only API Gateway can access it. We are working on VPC support which would obviate the need for making your EB publicly accessible (and with HTTPS), but I can't comment as to when this would be available.

In the meantime, our current suggested best practice is HTTPS with your backend configured to accept [client certificates](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/getting-started-client-side-ssl-authentication.html).

Comment: could you help me with one more thing?  I'm just working on client certificates. But I've got some problems. Currently, I use TCP port 80 on ELB in my EB. Is it good approach? Or is it impossible to use the client certificates through TCP and I should use EB with HTTPS (443)?

Comment: It should be possible, but if you don't have a good reason for binding to port 80, using port 443 will make it easier to configure later.

Comment: @BobKinney Just to clarify, the suggested best practice / compromise is terminating SSL in ELB and re-encrypting from ELB to EB. In such case, will ELB properly forward API Gateway's client certificate to EB? If not, is it possible and what actions should be taken? Thanks!

Comment: @joakim Unfortunately ELB/ALB do not handle the client certificate authentication, so you will need to operate the ELB in tcp load balancing mode and terminate SSL on your instances.

Comment: @BobKinney thanks! Wouldn't TCP mode affect the balancer's performance though? It's also leaving the instances open to DOS attacks. What if SSL is terminated in ELB which then re-encrypts the traffic and forwards it to the instances (where ingress would be limited to the ELB's IP range to limit the possibilities of outside access)? Would this work?

Comment: @joakim API Gateway does not publish its IP ranges, so IP based restrictions are not possible.

Comment: Thanks! What about the ELB's IP ranges? I guess I could still use the region's IP ranges. Regardless of that, is the re-encryption at the ELB a potentially valid placeholder approach?

Comment: @joakim What does ELB's IP ranges have to do with it? I'm not sure how encrypting between the ELB and your instances (all within your account) replaces encryption between API Gateway and your ELB.

Comment: @BobKinney It would not replace it, I would encrypt both the traffic from API Gateway to the ELB AND the traffic between the ELB and the instances. My hope here is that decrypting at the ELB before re-encrypting would help it with its decision making balancing wise and of course DDOS attacks. All answers at this thread suggest this is a valid workaround http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/30403/should-ssl-be-terminated-at-a-load-balancer

Comment: @BobKinney, To authenticate Client-Side SSL Certificate on my EB's instances (not ELB) I'm trying to use NGINX. But I can do that only if set also server certificate in my NGINX, am I right? So I need both: client and server certificates. So how to get and where to set server certificates? I assume that I have to buy one SSL Certificate and use its certificate and key (.crt, .key or .pem files). But certificate can be set only for specific domain (subdomain, wildcard subdomain). Do I need bind also my domain to EB if I want to use SSL certificate on EC2 instances behind ELB?

Comment: @joakim SSL between the ELB and your EC2 instances is largely over kill, but if you're willing to forgo the ability to verify the source of traffic, then yes your solution will work.

Comment: @nicq Yes you will need to get a server certificate from a 3rd party issuer. yes you will need to configure both the server certificate for serving traffic and the client certificate for authenticating it. Yes, you will need to have a domain pointing to your EB instance in order to use the server certificate.

Comment: @BobKinney I wrongly assumed that ELB supported client side certificates, which is why I thought about the re-encryption solution which would provide both source verification (via the client certificate) and ELB to EC2 HTTPS. Since this is not an option and TCP is the only way, are there any established best practices for reducing the potential for DDOS attacks and for helping the load balancer do its primary job with reduced visibility of the traffic (since it's simply passing everything as-is at layer 4)? Thanks!

Comment: @joakim Apologies, but that's not my area of expertise. Would recommend opening a new question to reach a broader audience who may have more experience.

Comment: @BobKinney Thanks for all the help! I'll probably go down the TCP route.